# My temp conversion program

Tags: java

I'm not sure why my program will not work. I was told that I should not put the getCelcius inside the constructor but now I'm stuck. Any help? I may also have some un wanted braces that are useless to the program.

```
import java.io.*;
class Temperature {
    //Assign varriables to int
    int factorC, factorF;
    int celcius, ferenheit;

    { 
        int getFactorC() { // Celsius
            return factorC;
        }
    }

    // declaring variables
    Temperature(int factorC, int factorF, int celcius, int ferenheit) {  
        setFactorC() {
            factorC = (9 / 5) * celcius + 32; //Calculate Celcius
        }
        {
            int getFactorF() { // Fahrenheit
                return factorF;
        }
    }

    {
        setFactorF() {
            factorF= (5 / 9) * ferenheit - 32; //Calculate Ferenheit
        }
    }
}
} //???

class TempConversion
{
```

Comment: Format your code please!

Comment: This is Java, not Lisp. Clean up those braces.

Comment: Wait this code wouldn't even compile under Lisp...

Comment: _"I may also have some un wanted braces_" Why do you have them there anyway?

Comment: You can't nest a method inside a constructor.

Comment: Scrap your entire program. Start from scratch with the most basic Java tutorial.

Comment: You will want to read up also on int division, since `5 / 9` always will return 0. You want to do double division using `5.0 / 9.0` instead. Sorry for being blunt, but it looks like you're guessing at this, like you're trying to learn how to code without first studying your book and course material. You will want to put a little more effort into this necessary study, either that or drop the course.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with your code, but the first thing I'm going to do it format it:

```
class Temperature {

    //Assign varriables to int
    int factorC, factorF;
    int celcius, ferenheit;

    int getFactorC() { // Celsius
        return factorC;
    }

    Temperature(int factorC, int factorF, int celcius, int ferenheit) {
        this.factorC = factorC;
        this.factorF = factorF;
        this.celcius = celcius;
        this.ferenheit = ferenheit;
    }

    void setFactorC() {
        factorC = (9 / 5) * celcius + 32; //Calculate Celcius
    }

    int getFactorF() { // Fahrenheit
        return factorF;
    }

    void setFactorF() {
        factorF = (5 / 9) * ferenheit - 32; //Calculate Ferenheit
    }
}
```

Quick tip:

- `9/5` is 1 and `5/9` is 0. In Java, when you divide integers, you get an integer. You can replace that with `9.0/5.0` and `5.0/9.0`.